Is the kingdom of God that Jesus talked about in John 3:3 different from the kingdom of God he talked about in John 3:5?
The two verses are:

John 3:3 - Jesus replied, “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can see
the kingdom of God unless he is born again/from above.”
John 3:5 - Jesus answered, “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can enter
the kingdom of God unless he is born of water and the Spirit.


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Why would you think that these two kingdoms might be different?  Please explain.

Thanks for this question, Tunes. My instant thought is, how can anyone enter into anything if they cannot even see it?

Unless there is some reason to believe otherwise, there is only one Kingdom of God (which no one can enter or even see) until they have been reborn as a spirit. (The difficulty I see here is quite different though: following Christ's return, most of the survivors of the Tribulation, who will be living into the Millennium, will then be living in the Kingdom (here on Earth) even though they have not yet been reborn or even learned about Jesus yet. Can "no one" be considered as referring only to the people living at that time, and not to the people living at Christ's return?)

No, it's the same kingdom, but Jesus explains how it is entered in a new way. Nicodemus cannot comprehend Jesus' first statement, since it was a new concept for him.  He is bewildered and tries to elicit additional information:

“How can a person once grown old be born again? Surely he cannot
reenter his mother’s womb and be born again, can he?”

So Jesus restates the teaching in clearer times emphasizing that "born again" is not meant literally: The rebirth is spiritual not physical, and it is effected through baptism. Both statements refer to spiritual regeneration, one emphasizing that it comes "from above," the other that is comes through baptism and the Holy Spirit.

We don't wash dirt off the body, but sin out off the heart. The water of the word.

ONE KINGDOM All throughout the New Testament there is only one divine Kingdom of God. Even when the phrase "Kingdom of Heaven" is used, there still is only one Kingdom.  The comparison of synoptic Gospels bears this out.
And as Believers we all are translated into the Kingdom of His dear Son. We are translated into the Kingdom of Light.
So Then What do these verses mean? First note that both verses are within the one discussion event. There are not two occasions here. So it is reasonable that only one Kingdom is referred to, with two aspects of it highlighted.
Jesus opens the discussion with the learned rabbi, Nicodemus, by saying that Unless one is born from above (Aramaic word), he cannot see the Kingdom. (3:3) And then Jesus expands and explains what He is trying to convey by adding, Unless one is born of the water and Spirit, he cannot enter the Kingdom. And adds for further explanation, *That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is born of Spirit is Spirit.
Jesus is trying to inform that "physical birth" (water) is not enough when it comes to the Kingdom citizenship. Earlier John wrote that the children of God are such, NOT because of of blood (Jewish DNA), nor of the will of flesh, nor of the will of man. (John 1:12-13) It's a God thing! And Jesus is telling Nicodemus the same thing: There has to be a spiritual transformation (a spiritual birthing) in a man before he can be considered a citizen in the Kingdom of God. It's a God method.
Common Mistake The first centuries Jews---and Nicodemus---were emmeshed in external rituals and a plethora of regulations that dealt with external conduct. But the Kingdom of God deals with an internal rewiring, renewing, reforming...a veritable rebirth. A rebirth in a heavenly maternity ward! (Paternity ward.)
Later Jesus taught the disciples about the need for cleansing the "inner part of the cup" and the "inner heart" for out of it the "mouth speaks." And of white-washed tombs but yet were full of dead men's bones.
One, not only can't enter the Kingdom, but cannot see the Kingdom, without a total spiritual rebirth!
